# Delete User from Azure AD B2C using Graph API right after it was created - ObjectNotFoundException

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Custom Policy to sign up users in Azure AD B2C.
In the last step, before the JWT is issue, the technical profile does the following:

```
<!-- Store the user in the AD -->
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" ContinueOnError="false" />
<!-- Sends the user information, including ObjectId to website to store locally-->
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-SendUserInformation" ContinueOnError="false"/>
```

So, this works fine. However, in my code, if something goes wrong in the step 2 (send the user's information to store locally), I call the Graph API to delete the user that was just created.
However, I noticed that the Graph API works when I "debug" (which means, taking some time to click next.. next...), but when it's running in the server, the user is not deleted from the AD.
It doesn't throw an exception.

My code to delete the user is the following:

```
        public AzureGraphService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var azureOptions = new AzureAdOptions();
            configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", azureOptions);

            // Client credential provider is used by services and desktop applications to acquire Microsoft Graph access token without a user.
            _confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(azureOptions.ClientId)
                .WithTenantId(azureOptions.Domain)
                .WithClientSecret(azureOptions.ClientSecret)
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(_confidentialClientApplication);

            // Set up the Microsoft Graph service client with client credentials
            _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
        }

        public async Task DeleteUserFromAD(string azuresubid)
        {
            try
            {
                // Delete user by object ID
                await _graphClient.Users[azuresubid]
                   .Request()
                   .DeleteAsync();          
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO - Log exception?
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

After looking the Audit Logs in Azure AD B2C, I found this 
"ObjectNotFoundException".

[image]

However, I'm certain that the object is correct and the objectID that I use to delete is also correct because it works if I "debug" (go slowly).

My question is:
Is there a delay between the Object (User) is created in the AD B2C and the time that I can actually see and delete the object from there?

Thank you

Comment: From your description, it seems that when you run the program directly, this user has not been created successfully. But when you debug (do ti slowly), it has been created successfully. Therefore it can be deleted. Can you set a time interval in the code to test?

Comment: Hello! The user is indeed created in the AD and I even get the objectID from azure to store in the DB during the registration in the same call to my REST api that might delete the user if something goes wrong. I tried to add a delay of 5s, but still the user isn't deleted from the AD and the same objectNotFound exception, which doesn't make any sense because when I see the audit log and the exception, the "target" is the correct objectID.

Comment: How did you call `DeleteUserFromAD` method? Can you print the azuresubid in `DeleteUserFromAD` method?

Comment: @TonyJu I call this method in another method by simply calling the method and passing the objectId
`await _azureGraphService.DeleteUserFromAD(objectId);`

Comment: @HenriqueBelotto Can you get the objectId in `DeleteUserFromAD ` method?

Comment: @TonyJu The objectID is sent to this method, I don't get from it. I'm not sure if I understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a delay, the policy execution targets the same DCs, your graph api call from your REST API is likely hitting a different DC and cannot find the account at that time. Use retry logic, try 3 times with a 5 second delay. Usually replication completes in 7sec.

Comment: Thank you!!
It worked, I added a retry logic with 5 seconds. Thank you

Comment: I set a delay for 10 seconds before deleting account (after account creation) and it did not help. No error is returned, so it looks like the DELETE operation was successful. And the user is still in Azure.

Comment: It completed successfully, but the user still exists in another DC (or as you refer to it, Azure), till that operation replicates across all DCs.